# Laravel: advantages or disadvantages of using slug instead of id

Tags: laravel, slug

I was wondering of what could be the **advantages** or **disadvantages** of using **slug instead of id** when looking for a model or for urls. 
Because there is a possibility to bind directly the url so that in the web.php file, this url `/users/{user}` will become the following:

with id:

```
domain.com/users/1
```

or with slug:

```
domain.com/users/IQii33XAQhldEK
```

Thanks

Comment: It depends on what your application is and the structure of it. I believe this is going to end up being an opinion based question and therefor its probably going to end up being not appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 2):

`IQii33XAQhldEK` is not a slug, a slug would be `domain.com/users/patrissol-kenfack`.

In the case of the slug, the 2 benefits are:

1. Better readability for humans,
2. Better for SEO, because Google will see the keywords in the URL.

Comment: `IQii33XAQhldEK` is more or less a slug, just would be `iqii33xaqhldek` (lowercase) if actually "sluggified". Slugs can be a single word, they don't need to have `-` in them, etc.

Comment: Some negatives to the readable version are decreased performance, less obfuscation and potentially non-unique slugs

Comment: Decreased performances is arguable, you could very well use the slug as primary key, or put an index on the column in your DB and it would have the same performances. Obfuscation is required only when it is required, and a slug is actually way more obfuscated than an ID (because the slug represents the content on the page while the ID is backend-only data). Now for non-uniqueness, just generate unique ones by appending an incremental number?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `id` in the url, it could mean that users would be able to know what the id of the resource they are viewing are. Usually, this won't be much of an issue, but if proper security practices are not followed, users could modify resources using this id by passing it implicitly (So make sure to use `$fillable` or `$guarded`) . For example, a malicious user could simply put a

```
<input type="text" name="id" value="<the-id-of-any-other-resource>"
```

And if you insert or update models with `$request->all()`, it could end up modifying the `id` of that resource.

Comment: In some cases, it can help to reveal statistics of your application to a certain degree too.. e.g. user ID 5000 is going to signify that you most likely have at least 5k users registered